# how to clear form data in django

Tags: python, django

I have created django form.py file :

```
from django import forms
from models import ResumeModel


class ResumeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
    fathers_name = forms.CharField(max_length = 200)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label='Your e-mail address')
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    class Meta():
        model = ResumeModel
        fields =('username','first_name','last_name','fathers_name','email','message')
```

**views.py :**

```
def save(request):
    if 'submit' in request.POST:
        form = ResumeForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = ResumeForm()
            return render(request, '/success/', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = ResumeForm()
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['form'] =form
    return render_to_response('create.html',args)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^save/', 'Resume.views.save'),
    url(r'^success/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='success.html')),
)
```

Now all is working fine. problem is that as i submit form it moves to success page and when i go back to previous page that is /save/ page it holds all the values in fields that i submitted. How to clear the fields if i press `back button to go back to that form page having url as "/save/ "`

Answer (score 1):

This is about the browsers behaviour. Browser shows u the page in its cache instead of calling a new page.

U may workaround this by using javascript.Unfortunately browser also dont run the javascript codes again.

But u may try :

```
$(window).bind("pageshow", function() {
  // Clean form values
});
```

by JQuery

Comment: where to write these lines>

Comment: Wherever u want. An example 
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquerymobile/tryit.asp?filename=tryjqmob_event_pageshow) from w3schools
.

Answer (score 1):

This is a browser implementation detail. You might be able to hack your way around it with JavaScript or break the cache etc. The subject is discussed in [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507793/best-way-for-back-button-to-leave-form-data?rq=1).

However a nicer UI approach might be to use AJAX to POST a serialised version of the form. If you successfully validate and process that form in your `view` (inserting a new row into your resume model table etc), you could then send a JSON response which might invoke some JavaScript to clear the form fields (maybe using [`.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.reset)). The user is then free to submit another form easily if that is the requirement.

Also note it is recommended that you use a [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) after a successful `POST` (you have a `render()` response at the moment). This stops the users re-submitting the form again and potentially duplicating rows in your databases etc.